# Condicionales en PHP

Tags: php, html, condiciones

Tengo el siguiente código en HTML y PHP. No encuentro el error en el código PHP, pues, no me lee las expresiones y no me arroja el resultado. La verdad soy nuevo en la programación.

```js
  $( document ).ready(function() 
                      {
  $("#boton_calcular").click(function()
                             {
    $.post("Rumbo_php.php",
           {
      azm: $("#azm1").val(),
    },
           function(data, status){
      console.log("Datos recibidos: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      if(status=='success')
      {

        $("#caja_resultado").val( data );
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
<?php 

    //Capturo parametros 
    $azm1 = $_POST['azm1'];
 
    //Realizo funcion para el paso de dms a deg
 
    function rm(azm)
    {
         
        $exp = $azm>=0 && $azm<=90;
        $exp1 = $azm>90 && $azm<=180;
        $exp2 = $azm>180 && $azm<=270;
        $exp3 = $azm>270 && $azm<=360;
          
        if (eval($exp))
        {
         echo("Rumbo Calculado es: N"+$azm+"E");
        } else if (eval($exp1)){
         echo("Rumbo Calculado es: S"+(180-$azm)+" E");
        } else if (eval($exp2)){
         echo("Rumbo Calculado es: S"+($azm-180)+"W");    
        } else if (eval($exp3)){
         echo("Rumbo Calculado es: N"+(360-$azm)+"W");    
        } else { 
         echo("No es un angulo valido");
        } 
        return $resultado;
    }

    //Calculo las coordenadas de el punto

    $rum = rm($azm1);

    echo $rum;

?>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
   </head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="azm1" value="3"> </input>Rumbo
<br><br>
<button id="boton_calcular">Calcular Rumbo</button> 
<input type="text" id="caja_resultado"> </input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu `PHP` tienes:

```
$azm1 = $_POST['azm1'];
```

Y en el `JavaScript`

```
$.post("Rumbo_php.php",
        {
            azm: $("#azm1").val(),              
        },
```

Ese `azm:` reemplazalo por `azm1:` quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
$.post("Rumbo_php.php",
        {
            azm1: $("#azm1").val(),             
        },
```

Reemplaza:

```
function rm(azm)
```

Por:

```
function rm($azm)
```

Tu funcion queda de la siguiente manera:

```
function rm($azm)
{
    $exp = ($azm>=0 && $azm<=90) ? true : false;
    $exp1 = ($azm>90 && $azm<=180) ? true : false;
    $exp2 = ($azm>180 && $azm<=270) ? true : false;
    $exp3 = ($azm>270 && $azm<=360) ? true : false; 
    $resultado = "";
    if ($exp)
    {
        $resultado = "Rumbo Calculado es: N". $azm ."E";
    } else if ($exp1){      
        $resultado = "Rumbo Calculado es: S".(180-$azm)." E";
    } else if ($exp2){
        $resultado = "Rumbo Calculado es: S".($azm-180)."W";    
    } else if ($exp3){
        $resultado = "Rumbo Calculado es: N".(360-$azm)."W";    
    } else { 
        $resultado = "No es un angulo valido";
    } 
return $resultado;
}
//Calculo las coordenadas de el punto   
$rum = rm($azm1);   
echo $rum;
?>
```

El problema que vi es que la contatenación de cadenas en `PHP` lo estabas realizando con el signo `+` sin embargo se realiza con el punto `.`

Por otro lado, cuando defines variables que almacenarán valores boolean (true/false) es mejor darlos a conocer, hice un "If corto":

```
Variable = (condicion) ? Sí cumple : no cumple;
```

Si lo hago de manera tradicional sería:

```
Variable;
if (condicion) { 
//hacer algo si es verdad como asignar el valor a la variable:
Variable = algo si la condición es verdadera;
}else{ 
//hacer algo si la condición no se cumple, como asignarle otro valor a la variable:
Variable = algo si la condición es falsa;
}
```

El uso de `eval` a mi parecer estaba siendo extra, por lo que lo retiré ya que la función estaba evaluando si la condición era verdadera o falsa.

Para retornar valores de las funciones, éstas deben estar siendo utilizadas, la variable `$resultado` se quedaba definida pero en blanco.

Puedes ver un pequeño ejemplo corriendo en: https://lamp-fredyfx.c9users.io/soes.php?azm1=89 //Estará funcionando temporalmente

solo reemplaza ese 89 por los valores que gustes.

Por cierto, ya que quieres aprender `PHP` aquí te dejo unas websites, espero te sean de utilidad:

1. https://www.codecademy.com/es/tracks/php-clone
2. http://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=70&Itemid=193
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNbTvInths0
4. http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/phpya/
5. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/index.htm

Para `JavaScript` y `jQuery`

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript
2. http://try.jquery.com/
3. https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript
4. http://learn-js.org/
5. https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery

Comment: muchas gracias por la información, y por la ayuda en el código, aunque me sigue apareciendo un error no me lee el eval(): Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\Taller_php\rumbo\Rumbo_php.php(17) : eval()'d code on line 1
No es un angulo valido.

Comment: Muchas gracias, corre perfecto, tienes razon en esa concatenación, es de tener mas cuidado, por último y abusando de tu amabilidad me podrias indicar la función del ? true: false; es decir el . concatena y el ? q función cumpliria.

Comment: entendido, muchas gracias nuevamente

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46032/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-js28).

Comment: hey @JS28 podrías eliminar los comentarios por favor? he eliminado los míos para que haya orden en el sitio, todos los comentarios los he movido a un chat donde se podrá visualizar lo que ambos hemos redactado. saludos

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un **$** en el parámetro de la función. Para el problema del eval, reemplázalo por mirar directamente el booleano. Debiera quedar así:

```
function rm($azm)
{

$exp = $azm>=0 && $azm<=90;
$exp1 = $azm>90 && $azm<=180;
$exp2 = $azm>180 && $azm<=270;
$exp3 = $azm>270 && $azm<=360;

   if ($exp)
{
echo("Rumbo Calculado es: N"+$azm+"E");
} else if ($exp1){      
 echo("Rumbo Calculado es: S"+(180-$azm)+" E");
} else if ($exp2){
 echo("Rumbo Calculado es: S"+($azm-180)+"W");    
} else if ($exp3){
 echo("Rumbo Calculado es: N"+(360-$azm)+"W");    
} else { 
 echo("No es un angulo valido");
} 
    return $resultado;

}
```

Tal como decia @fredyfx mira el código javascript y reemplázalo por lo que el sugiere

Mira el log de error del servidor web. En apache aparecía esto:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: resultado in /home/roberto/public_html/Rumbo_php.php on line 29, referer: http://localhost/~roberto/sof.html
```

Lo que facilitaba la búsqueda de tu problema

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, tienes toda la razón, aunque me sigue apareciendo un error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\Taller_php\rumbo\Rumbo_php.php(17) : eval()'d code on line 1 No es un angulo valido, es como si no me reconociera el eval o las expresiones.